# c# windows form datagridview cell display text

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I bind the datagrid from the data i get from the database using code as below

dgvName.Datasource = ds.Table[0];

The data as below

```
Id      Name       Active
1       Test       1
2       Test1      0
3       Test3      0
```

I wish to display the active as "Y" or "No" instead of 1 or 0.  I try CellFormatting handler but it's not work.  Active datatype is int.  How I can do that?  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest you could think is: Add a new property on your class, for example

```
public string ActiveText 
  {
     get { return _active ? "Y" : "N"; } 
  }
```

and bind it to column you want